# Index out of range error on dataset while using train_test_split

Tags: pandas, numpy, sklearn-pandas

I am sure the answer is simple but I can't find it. I have the following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
#To preserve indices
indices = features.index.values 
# use the indices instead of y to save the order of the split.

X_train, X_test,indices_train,indices_test = train_test_split(X,indices, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(indices_train.shape)
print(indices_test.shape)
print(features.shape)
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
y_train, y_test = y[indices_train],  y[indices_test]
```

the prints of the shapes are as follows:

```
(126704, 260)
(31677, 260)
(126704,)
(31677,)
(158381, 14)
(158381, 260)
(158381,)
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error when the indices_train and indices_test arrays are within the bounds of y. Any direction appreciated. Here is the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/cf/ft88j_856fv5rk3whgs12d9w0000gq/T/ipykernel_5191/3590394404.py in <module>
     10 print(indices_train.shape)
     11 print(indices_test.shape)
---> 12 y_train, y_test = y[indices_train],  y[indices_test]

IndexError: index 162609 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 158381
```

Comment: You only give `X` shape, where is your `y`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, apologies, I have updated to show the shape of `y` as well as the shape of `features`

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer was that I had old indices from a larger dataset so running the following on features before splitting into X and y was the key:

```
features.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```